# powershell multi-threaded script for sql. Where to start?

Tags: sql, multithreading, powershell

So right now we have a sub script that basically iterates through a collection of SQL DBs and runs a given upgrade script to that DB. This works fine, but sometimes our scripts can be a bit intensive (adding columns, populating new columns, changing column lengths, etc) and end up taking forever. The bottle neck being it's apply the same script to one DB at a time.

Is there a way to multithread the script so it applies the script to every DB at the same time? All answers or links to blogs/documentation are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article on the subject of Powershell multithreading at: http://www.get-blog.com/?p=189

There is a lot of example code there for maximum multithreading pleasure.

**Edit:**
However, I would like to add a small warning for running major DDL queries on many databases on the same production server at the same time.

Depending on how much data, what recovery models you have and things like that, you might send the server into free fall and end up in really crazy situations where half the databases are unavailable and refuses to be contacted. So start slow with a few of the databases at the same time, and test that first.

Comment: This is great! Get's my feet wet with multithreading. Already have an idea of how I can easily implement some basic multithreading into our architecture. You rock Nicklas. And I'll be sure to test extensively in Qa before attempting prod.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on  it, FWIW:

[Invoke-ScriptAsynch](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/)